# Is Bootstrap 3 really responsive by default?

Tags: responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to create a new application widget using bootstrap 3 and other web technologies like angular etc. I know that the new version of bootstrap is responsive. My understanding after reading the documentation is that the widget that I will create will automatically be responsive. I don't need to do anything special to make it responsive. However If I want to make it non-responsive then I need to make necessary changes to disable this functionality of bootstrap 3.

**Can you please let me know that whether my understanding of Bootstrap in this regard is correct or not?**

Comment: It's too broad for SO (IMO) anyway: no. Write a simple "Hello World" HTML page, include Bootstrap. Is it responsive? No. You have to setup your layout to be responsive (and various other stuffs). Bootstrap just makes it pretty easy.

Comment: Thanks Adriano, Can you please share a link where I can have a guide for the responsive layout?

Comment: This has it all you need to know, including the ability to disable responsiveness: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 3):

I think this will help you to understand more about Bootstrap.

You mentioned *"widget that I will create will automatically be responsive"*. But if you not apply Bootstrap CSS rules in your widget, it will not be responsive even it in inside of Bootstrap template.

We have to apply Bootstrap CSS rules in our design to take effect and be responsive. If you do not want a particular element to be responsive, apply your own CSS rules or media queries on breaking points that you want...

Link for Bootstrap CSS http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Hope this will help you. Cheers! (='.'=)

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need to do:

Steps to disable page responsiveness
Omit the viewport  mentioned in the CSS docs
Override the width on the .container for each grid tier with a single width, for example width: 970px !important; Be sure that this comes after the default Bootstrap CSS. You can optionally avoid the !important with media queries or some selector-fu.
If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding behavior.
For grid layouts, use .col-xs-* classes in addition to, or in place of, the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device grid scales to all resolutions.
You'll still need Respond.js for IE8 (since our media queries are still there and need to be processed). This disables the "mobile site" aspects of Bootstrap.

Bootstrap template with responsiveness disabled
We've applied these steps to an example. Read its source code to see the specific changes implemented.

Not Responsive Template: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/